# How to move files from the end of the drive to the beginning?

Tags: filesystem

I am trying to create a partition of 100GB on a 900GB SSD.
However, when I go to create the partition Widows Disk Manager says that there is only 1 GB of available space even though File Explorer says that there are 600GB free space.
[image]
defraggler shows that there are some files at the end of the drive I am trying to partition, which are preventing the partition from having more than 1GB of linear free space.
How to move these files to the beginning or even middle of the drive so that Disk Manager can partition 100GB of the free space?